# Case Clicker Bot

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I'm trying to create a bot that automatically opens cases and buys more when there isn't more to open. When I try to find the inventory by using

```
page_soup.findAll("div", id = "inventoryItems")
```

I get this error

```
'str' object has no attribute 'descendants'
```

I have tried googling the error and watched a lot of bs4 vids, but can't seem to find the solution.

Link to the webside: https://mtsl.dk/csgo/

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
    from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

    url = 'https://mtsl.dk/csgo/'
    page = uReq(url)
    page_soup = soup(page, 'html.parser')

    #outer_inventory = page_soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'show page')
    inventory = []

    inventory = soup.findAll('div', id = 'inventoryItems')
    #print(inner_inventory)

    #cases = inventory.findAll('div', {'class_= item'})
    #print(cases[0])
    #case = cases[0]

    #for case in cases:
    #   case_name = case.findAll('div', {'class: title'})
    #   print(case_name)
```

Comment: This webpage is rendered with JavaScript using XHR. Given you want to perform actions on the webpage ("automatically opens cases and buys more") I suggest you use Selenium which renders the JavaScript and allows you to perform actions.

Comment: I agree with @Dan-Dev. You need to perform some action on the page. Also, the website returns the response with Request as follows
<h2>406 - Client browser does not accept the MIME type of the requested page.</h2>
So I suggest use of Selenium.

Comment: Yeah i was gonna use selenium to open the case but bs4 to find out the specfic cases because i want it to open the good cases first but Thanks i gonna try that.